# Saving PyTorch model output in .mat format gives empty matrix

Tags: python, matlab, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am taking output of some layers in my model and trying to save it in .mat format. But the matrix is empty! Could someone help, please. Thanks

```
out_recon, my_feat = model(in_imgs)
my_feat = np.array(my_feat)
print("my_feat", my_feat[0].shape)
scipy.io.savemat('test.mat', {'mydata': my_feat[0]})
```

My feat size:
my_feat torch.Size([1, 512, 1, 24, 24])

Comment: can you please try checking by using my_feat[0].cpu().numpy()

Comment: yes, that works for my_feat[0], thanks! But now when I do scipy.io.savemat('test1.mat', {'mydata': my_feat}), this gives me empty matrix!

Comment: for this please try similar my_feat.cpu().numpy() . if this works please tell me i will add this as answer

Comment: when I do my_feat.cpu().numpy(), it gives an AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'cpu'

Comment: my_feat = np.array(my_feat) , can you please comment this line and try once

Comment: now says: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cpu'!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234076/discussion-between-nima-and-kishore-v-m).

Comment: code snippet updated in chat . please check